# jq - Combine data from different keys

Tags: json, key, jq

I have this json output

```
{
"FileSystems": [
    {
        "CreationToken": "CreationToken1",
        "OwnerId": "OwnerId1",
        "SizeInBytes": {
            "Timestamp": 1552377599.0,
            "Value": 1550721024
        },
        "Name": "Name1",
        "NumberOfMountTargets": 3,
        "FileSystemId": "fs-1",
        "LifeCycleState": "available",
        "CreationTime": 1550506468.0,
        "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose"
    },
    {
        "CreationToken": "CreationToken2",
        "OwnerId": "OwnerId2",
        "SizeInBytes": {
            "Timestamp": 1552377599.0,
            "Value": 2390339584
        },
        "Name": "Name2",
        "NumberOfMountTargets": 3,
        "FileSystemId": "fs-2",
        "LifeCycleState": "available",
        "CreationTime": 1547663741.0,
        "PerformanceMode": "generalPurpose"
    }
]
}
```

By using this command

```
aws efs describe-file-systems | jq -r ".FileSystems[] | .SizeInBytes.Value"
```

I can recieve the NFS sized values:

```
1550725120
2390339584
```

But I need to get an output with the filesystem Name, so it should be like that:

```
Name1: 1550725120
Name2: 2390339584
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo)), like this:

```
jq -r ".FileSystems[] | \"\(.Name) \(.SizeInBytes.Value)\""
```